# PIMPL на unique или shared указателях?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, smart-pointer

Привожу код заготовки реализации идиомы pImpl с этого [сайта](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/).

```
// in header file
class widget 
{
public:
    widget();
    ~widget();
private:
    class impl;
    unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};

// in implementation file
class widget::impl 
{
    // :::
};

widget::widget() : pimpl{ new impl{ /*...*/ } } { }
widget::~widget() { }
```

Далее там написано следующее:

> Prefer to hold the Pimpl using a unique_ptr. It’s more efficient than
>   using a shared_ptr, and correctly expresses the intent that the Pimpl
>   object should not be shared.

**Вопрос**: в чем конкретно эффективность (предпочтительное более быстрое перемещение?) использования `std::unique_ptr` и почему предлагается не разделять реализацию между несколькими экземплярами? Я ранее задавал вопрос относительно идиомы copy-on-write, почему бы не использовать реализацию идиомы pImpl на указателе типа `shared_ptr` и дополнить ее вот такими реализациями операторов, характерными для COW идиомы:

```
    // Non-const * and -> , copying
    T& operator*()
    {
        copy();
        return *m_sp;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        copy();
        return m_sp.operator->();
    }

    // Const * and -> methods no need to copy
    const T& operator*() const
    {
        return *m_sp;
    }

    const T* operator->() const
    {
        return m_sp.operator->();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала нужно понимать разницу в идеологии между shared_ptr и unique_ptr. Первый подразумевает, что объект будет в общем владении, а unique_ptr  только единоличное владение. Так как pimpl подразумевает единоличное владение (не, можно конечно сделать и расшаренное, но это как то не нормально), то unique_ptr в самый раз.

Почему же оно быстрее? все очень просто. shared_ptr внутри себя содержит как минимум счетчик ссылок либо на атомиках, либо с мютексами. В любом случае это не быстро. unique_ptr это все не нужно. В многих случаях компилятор может оптимизировать до  такой степени, что будет не хуже голого указателя.

> почему предлагается не разделять реализацию между несколькими экземплярами

потому что это будет уже не pimpl.

> дополнить ее вот такими реализациями операторов, характерными для COW идиомы:

Ваша реализация требует наличие некой функции copy. И второе - она не очень thread-safe.

Почему такое не сделали в shared_ptr? Потому что это был бы cow_ptr. Это лишняя функциональность, которая обычно не нужна (если бы она была нужна, то наверно она появилась бы и в бусте, откуда пришел этот умный указатель), а в с++ не принято "платить за то, что не используется".

Answer (score 1):

Если вы дополните умный указатель этими операторами - это будет уже не `shared_ptr`, а уже какой-нибудь `cow_ptr`. И да, так тоже будет работать. Тут главное - найти способ вынести `copy()` в модуль реализации, потому что нельзя скопировать необъявленный тип данных.

Как-то так в итоге должно получиться:

```
class widget 
{
public:
    widget();
    ~widget();
private:
    class impl;
    impl* copy(pimpl* impl);
    cow_ptr<impl, &widget::copy> pimpl;
};
```

---

Однако, на самом деле операция копирования объекта - очень странная по смыслу. И в большинстве прикладных случаев ее явно запрещают. А если копирование запрещено архитектурно, то зачем все эти сложности с реализацией?